# In the US, is it legal for me to commercially advertise a photograph that I took myself of a bottle of Coke?

Tags: united-states, copyright

Where would I find in https://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap1.html for example or other legal text whether it is legal for me to publish my photograph of a bottle of Coke for use to sell that bottle of Coke in my advertisement that I created, all commercially?

Answer (score 4):

Yes it would be legal to do so.

A full analysis would look at trademark law (where the bottom line is that the use of the Coke mark is not misleading since you are selling bona fide Coke), and copyright law.

Whether it was non-infringing or fair use, is a closer call, but there is little doubt that one way or the other, this would be legal.